# Delete cell from UITableView and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I try to delete cell (left swipe) and remove data from Firebase Database and Storage. Using this code:

```
struct Records {

let title: String
let source: String
var length: String
let recordUrl: String
let username: String

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
    self.source = dictionary["source"] as? String ?? ""
    self.length = dictionary["length"] as? String ?? ""
    self.recordUrl = dictionary["recordUrl"] as? String ?? ""
    self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
}
}
```

I've got a var

```
var records = [Records]()
```

Trying to delete cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        records.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
       Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("records").removeValue()
    }
    }
```

Firebase JSON [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tVnl.png)

I need to delete item inside "records"(appears as cell in my TableView), but now using my code I delete whole "records"

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the ID for the records too. This way you can create a path to that particular record.  After that just add one more child in the path.

Like this.

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("records").child(record.id).removeValue()
```

Comment: Hi, rv7284. Thanx, good idea, but how can I create an ID for each records?)

Comment: you have already done that. See how each record falls under a unique key. You must have used childByAutoId(). You can get that id from that part using '.key'.

Answer (score 0):

Got some new. Can get key of all items in branch "records"

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("records")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
let record = self.records[indexPath.item]
dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
                print("Key \(key)")
```

but still can't get an id to delete of current item (record in branch "records")